# Google Apps Script Google Sheets Update Without Opening

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

and Im using it to autoamte some personal stuff with finance, but I observed that it doesnt runs when the sheet is closed. How do I make it so the updates are being reflected even if its closed?

What I tried:

Syncing it with firebase. but when I made changes in firebase it wont reflect it on a sheet[Didn't work]

Backend bot opening it in intervals so it could recieved the updates then closing it. [Works but I think its Bad Practice]

Comment: Can you add what have you tried till now?

Comment: @Gangula done, cheers

Comment: I would like to confirm whether my understanding is correct. In your situation, you want to refresh **the values calculated by custom functions** without opening the Spreadsheet. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: My sheets fetches data from an API which gives updates in intervals.So this means I have to open the sheet in order to update the values

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your situation. In your situation, you update the Spreadsheet by a Google Apps Script using the time-driven trigger. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes indeed, your english is awesome, I should be the one who's sorry for not explaining correctly.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could understand that you update the values on Spreadsheet using the Google Apps script with the time-driven trigger. If my understanding is correct, can you show your current script? Because when the script put the values to the cells, the values are updated without opening the Spreadsheet. So I would like to confirm your script. Can you show it?